# Static method in base class reflect the derived class name

Tags: c++, inheritance, reflection, static-methods

Here is base class:

```cpp
class Product
{
public:
    static void RegisterClass() {
        string b = __FUNCTION__;
    };
}
```

and here is the derived class.

```cpp
class Milk: Product
{}
```

in the main function I call the static method this way:

```cpp
main(){
    Milk.RegisterClass();
}
```

Then it writes value `Product::RegisterClass` into variable `b`. Is there a way to get value `Milk::RegisterClass` in the static method.

I don't want to instantiate the classes. And the main goal behind this scenario is to register `Milk` string somewhere.

Comment: I think you're out of luck. There is no `Milk::RegisterClass`. There is only Zuul... Er `Product::RegisterClass`.

Comment: Can you please expand on your actual use case here?  As written, this example is contrived and every single snippet has at least one error in it.  Where are these things being "registered"?  Rather than have classes register themselves, consider a more usual pattern (_e.g._ a class factory) where you can register all your classes by name and string with a simple macro and no need for any registration function on the class itself.

Comment: Static class methods do not belong to any instance of a class, neither base nor derived. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: Would modifying the structure to introduce CRTP be acceptable for your use case? If so, you can do something like: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WqK3dGezb

Comment: @paddy they are going to be registered in a txt file, so later a python script can read it. Class factory also seems convincing here, but I didn't want to create class factory for each derived classes, and looking for something more simple.

Comment: With respect to the above comment, the usual caveats on `std::type_info::name` apply. There are no solid guarantess about how usable or readable the output will be.

Comment: @Frank this actually looks very nice. I need to try it on couple of our compilers. Is there any limitation with compiler version or c++ version?

Comment: as @user4581301 mentionned, `type_info::name` is a bit of a mixed bag, and you can do much [nicer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9WYajKdTa) than that. As far as other caveats go, if `Product` is polymorphic, you'll need to add at least one more layer of indirection as well, but otherwise, this is a well-established and well-supported technique.

Comment: A class factory approach does not need to be complicated.  Here is an example I knocked up quickly to demonstrate: https://godbolt.org/z/5vvdeTo3G

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fairly constrained scenario presented by OP can be achieved reasonably well with the use of CRTP.

As pointed out in the comments, `type_info::name()` is fraught with uncertainty, so a better approach would be to explicitly state the string to use:

```
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

template<typename CRTP>
class Product
{
public:
    static void RegisterClass() {
        std::string b{CRTP::product_name};
        std::cout << b << "\n";
    };
};

class Milk : public Product<Milk> {
public:
    static constexpr std::string_view product_name{"Milk"};
};

int main() {
    Milk::RegisterClass();
}
```